# How to detect jQuery UI radio change event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, radio-button

I have 2 radio controls:

```
<fieldset id="sort">
                <label for="sort">Sort: </label>
                <input class="sortDirection" type="radio" id="asc" name="sortDirection"><label for="asc">asc</label>
                <input class="sortDirection" type="radio" id="desc" name="sortDirection"><label for="desc">desc</label>
</fieldset>
```

Here's the jquery I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sort').buttonset();
});

$('#asc').on("change", function(event){
        alert("CHANGE EVENT!");
});
```

I also tried (with same results):

```
$('#sort input[type="radio"]').on("change", function(event){
        alert("CHANGE EVENT!");
});
```

The alert is never executed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried on `change` event?

Comment: Seems to be working here .. http://jsfiddle.net/rcK9h/

Comment: @Sushanth, it didn't work because even listeners should be inside onload function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Events must be within the **$(document).ready** or  **window.onload**

this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sort').buttonset();
});
```

**should be**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sort').buttonset();

        // events  
        $('#asc').on("change", function(event){
              alert("CHANGE EVENT!");
        });
});
```

Comment: If the event is attached to an element the code needs to run after the DOM tree has been generated or else it will not find what it's looking for, with `$(document).ready();` you check that it is;.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("change", ".sortDirection", function(){
    alert("changed");
    //insert code here
});​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SWQSS/)**

I would suggest using the `change` event instead of the `click` event. `change` does not fire again when the same option is `click`ed twice.

Comment: Please make sure your code is within the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`. Plus, the current implementation of `$("#asc").change()` will only fire when the element with `id` of `asc` is selected, and not when either radio buttons are selected.

Comment: #asc was just to test, I will use #sort once I have it working, my code didn't work because it wasn't inside .ready but your example doesn't work even if inside .ready.

Comment: Does the example on jsfiddle not work correctly for you? Because this is the correct implementation for a `change` event using `on`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.sortDirection').click(function(event){
        alert("CHANGE EVENT!");
});
```

Comment: `click(fn)` is just a shortcut to `on('click', fn)`

Comment: @elclanrs, are you saying that shortcuts are not meant to be used? :)

Comment: I think what he was saying is that you didn't need to change my code (possibly making me and other think that .on was the mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Since '#sort' is the buttonset, I think it should be:

```
$('#sort').on("change", function(event){
    alert("CHANGE EVENT!");
});
```

Comment: @DominicM For sure you have to bind the click/ change event when the document is ready, but in the fiddle you can click the desc button without and nothing happens, although the state of asc is changing. Therefore I think it would be better to bind the event on the parent element.

Comment: Like I said in other comments, I only used #asc in this example for simplicity.